# mysqli_real_escape and ctyle_alnum not working properly?

Tags: php

i am currently having problem using mysql_real_escape_string and ctype_alnum, here is my code:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['u'])) {
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET['u']);
    echo $username;
    if (ctype_alnum($username)) {
    //check user exists
    $check = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT username, first_name FROM users2 WHERE username='$username'");
    if (mysqli_num_rows($check)===1) {
    $get = mysqli_fetch_assoc($check);
    $username = $get['username'];
    $firstname = $get['first_name'];    
    }
    else
    {
    echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0; url=/index.php\">"; 
    exit();
    }
    }
}
?>
```

whenever i try to output $username it doesn't diplay anything, i am using this code to visit pages like profile.php?u=rahulkapoor

Comment: First parameter of [`mysqli_real_escape_string`](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) should be your connection.

Comment: Firstly echo $_GET['u'] to see is empty or not!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`mysqli_real_escape_string`](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) needs the connection as the first parameter:

```
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_GET['u']);
```